# How to make git bash on Windows not emit `\r`?

Tags: bash, newlines, git-for-windows

#### Problem statement

I'm on Windows, and sometimes would like to execute commands inside docker containers, but I'm unable to execute those with the error `<command>\r: command not found`. For instance:

```
$ docker run --interactive ubuntu:22.04
ls
/bin/bash: line 1: $'ls\r': command not found
```

#### Possible solutions?

- Is the the end of line character configurable in Git for Windows? I can't find it
- Or maybe a solution lies in a way of removing all `\r` characters on the stdin to the container's bash, for instance something along the lines of this

```
docker run --interactive ubuntu:22.04 "bash" "-c" "sed 's/\r//g' | bash"
```

but I couldn't get that to work. It almost works but not quite because the output isn't printed until the interactive session is disconnected. It also seems overly complicated.

In the broader picture I don't understand why this is a problem in *some* containers, but not all.

#### What I've tried

- I have this problem in the terminal provided by Git for Windows, as well as vscode's integrated terminal.
- Even if I have `ls<LF>` on the clipboard and paste it, I still get the same error.
- Note that this question is similar but different to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966488/how-do-i-fix-r-command-not-found-errors-running-bash-scripts-in-wsl), as I have the same problem but in interactive mode.
- As a workaround I append `#` to every line (effectively making the `\r` a comment), but this is effort and inflexible.

Answer (score 1):

You may set the shell to ignore Windows line-endings (skip `\r`)
with the following command:

```
set -o igncr
```

You may also define `SHELLOPTS` as a Windows environment variable and
set it to `igncr`. This way, every bash instance will inherit this option.

Comment: Neither `set -o igncr && docker run -i ubuntu:22.04` nor `docker run -i ubuntu:22.04; 
set -o igncr #` (# to omit CR) seem to work. What command exactly did you have in mind?

Comment: I don't have your environment. Do you say that the correct syntax is `set -o igncr #` ? My advice about SHELLOPTS probably needs more work in the Docker environment, but I can't test this.

Comment: I guess I was asking, should `set -o igncr` be set in the Windows host terminal or in the docker container terminal. Concretely my two commands are the best I could make of your suggestion, and, although much appreciated :), they don't help. Neither did global `SHELLOPTS` env var + reboot

Answer (score 1):

I have a Simple Solution to work-around your Strange Issue : (A) What-ever command you want should be terminated by " ; " : **Space SemiColon Space**. (B) You might even consider using `echo DONE` command at the end.

```
$ docker run --interactive ubuntu:22.04
ls ; 
<<ls output here>>
/bin/bash: line 1: $' \r': command not found
```

```
$ docker run --interactive ubuntu:22.04
echo EXECUTING ; pwd ; ls ; echo DONE
<<echo output here : EXECUTING>>
<<pwd output here>>
<<ls output here>>
<<echo output here : DONE\r>>
```

Comment: Adding `;` works, although there's the slight downside that every command then also prints `/bin/bash: line 1: $'\r': command not found`. Instead I had a workaround with a similar idea which is typing `#` at the end of each line. Same for appending `echo ""` (that also just consumes the `\r` into the echoed statement). But I was hoping for a more fix-once-and-for-all kind of solution.